# new Highcharts.chart returns an array of charts [undefined, a.chart]

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a function that creates new Highcharts. However, when I create a new chart, and log the Highcharts.charts array after, it shows an undefined element in the array. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<!-- Div to hold the occ chart -->
<div id="dialog2">
    <div id="canvas2" width="600" height="400"></div>
</div>

$("#divId").click(function() {
    createChart('canvas2', occChartOpts);
    theDialog2.dialog('open');   
})

//general function to create chart
function createChart(id, options) {
    return new Highcharts.chart(id, options);
}

//options object for occupancy chart
var occChartOpts = {
    chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Hourly Home vs Office Occupancy'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            '12am - 4am',
            '4am - 8am',
            '8am - 12pm',
            '12pm - 4pm',
            '4pm - 8pm',
            '8pm - 12am'
        ],
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Percent'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        areaspline: {
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Home',
        data: [95, 55, 10, 15, 45, 90]
    }, {
        name: 'Office',
        data: [5, 45, 90, 85, 55, 10]
    }]
}
```

Comment: So modify the array directly, by Array.prototype.shift(). Why would you want to change that behaviour?

Comment: So I was writing a response to you detailing how I did that but that it did not work properly, and I realized I did it wrong. So that solution worked just fine to result in an undefined free array. However, do you know why this happens in the first place? The odd thing is, I have 2 charts, and this only happens when I create one, not the other. I cannot spot the difference in code.